# ¿Cómo realizar una captura de div correctamente?

Tags: javascript, html, c3.js

Estoy generando graficas con la libreria c3.js la cual utiliza una hoja de estilos, entonces con la libreria html2canvas.js estoy capturando esas imagenes, el problema es que al hacer la captura la grafica sale mal en la imagen, es como si no tuviera su hoja de estilos. hay una manera de solucionar esto?

Asi capturo la imagen del div:

```
  $("#btn-Preview-Image").click(function() { 
    html2canvas([document.getElementById("chart")], {
      onrendered: function (canvas) {
     var img = canvas.toDataURL('image/png'); //o por 'image/jpeg' 
     //display 64bit imag
     document.write('<img src="'+img+'"/>');       
      }
    })
  })
```

Comment: capturas la imagen y la escribes sin especificarle estilo, ah no ser que lo definas en otro lado, usando el árbol DOM , pero no entiendo a que te refieres con que no carga el estilo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Descubri que la imagen no se generaba correctamente ya que C3.js utiliza su propia hoja de estilos css y al capturar la imagen omite la hoja de estilo por lo cual la imagen sale mal, recomendable cambiar de libreria a chart.js, chartist.js o cualquier otra que no utilice css